# Jquery select all selected and checked elements at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need is, find all selected elements on a page (I can do this by using `$(":selected")`) and find all checked elements on a page (I can do this by using `$(":checked")`).

Is there any way to find all selected and checked elements by using only one jQuery statement/selector?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the following?:

```
$(":selected, :checked")
```

Here an example of how you can do it:

```
if ($( ":checked, :selected"))
{
  $( "#message" ).html( "BOTH Select box and Checkbox are choosen!" );
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/14qsvu6L/2/)

Comment: @Parashuram Did this answer your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use can use

```
$(':checked, :selected')
```

This will select all the checked and selected elements.